# awk print first line and last line of instance

Tags: bash, awk

ok so i have some code that need help

Using AWK scan file  and extract the lines that have activity for the IP address 192.168.122.1

Print out  3 lines of output

```
 a) date/time first activity on the IP address was detected

 b) date/time last activity on the IP address was detected

 c) Total number of events detected on the IP address
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of how the input data is formatted?

Comment: Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::f16:e258:f40e:ee97 on ens33.
Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.15.150 on ens33.
Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Withdrawing workstation service for ens33.
Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Withdrawing workstation service for lo.
Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Host name conflict, retrying with CentOSBind-152
Aug 10 06:44:19 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[676]: Registering new address record for 192.168.122.1 on virbr0.IPv4.

Comment: its a basic log file. i need to print out the first time the ip addrees appears. then the last time it appears

Comment: Thanks, I posted a basic answer below. If that doesn't work for you, could you edit your question to include the formatted input data (instead of in a comment) and also the desired output format?

Comment: Show us the code you need help with so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've said so far, something like this might work for you:

```
# find all lines containing the IP
grep -F 192.168.122.1 FILE > tmp   

head -n1 tmp    # print first such line
tail -n1 tmp    # print last such line
wc -l tmp       # count the number of such lines
```

If you must use awk, here is one way:

```
# invoke as:
#     awk -f this_file.awk FILE

BEGIN {
    count = 0
}

/192\.168\.122\.1/ {
    if (count == 0) {
        print $0   # print the first line containing the IP
        last = $0  # in case the first line also happends to be the last
        count = 1
    } else {
        count += 1  # record that another line contained the IP
        last = $0  # remember this line in case it ends up being the last
    }
}

END {
    if (count > 0) {
        print last  # print the last line containing the IP
    }
    print count
}
```

Comment: thank you its works. but the problem i need a solution using AWK is some way

Comment: @ryanharmon Why do you need awk? Sounds like it might be an important part of the question.

Comment: in a class we are experimenting with AWK command and using it in scripts. as the actual out put is not important the execution is though

Comment: @ryanharmon I have updated my answer with an awk solution as well